# Font-family Converter output SVG line animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, svg

I want to achieve such a web effect.
It’s like the animation effect of the text writing path after text input.

Like this.==>[codepen](https://codepen.io/munkholm/pen/EaZJQE)

```
<svg ...>
  <path class="path" stroke="#000000" ... >
</svg>
svg {
  stroke-width:17;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  transition:transform .5s ease-out;
  path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1200;
    stroke-width:5;
    animation:summerbird-s .75s linear forwards .5s;
  }
}
```

And I learned that it is implemented using svg-path and stroke-dashoffset.

[Reference documentation1](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

[Reference documentation2](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dashoffset/)

---

And this is my code and it doesn't work

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .seriftext {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      font-size: 48px;
      stroke-dasharray: 1000;
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
      animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
    }
    @keyframes dash {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <text x="10" y="100" class="seriftext">
    Some text
  </text>
</svg>
```

But I still need to convert the font family to svg path. It would be great if there is a better implementation process or a suitable js library to help me.

Hope I can get other thoughts and help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Some Text</title>
  <style>


    .seriftext {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      font-size: 48px;
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-dasharray: 1000;
      stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
      animation: dash 5s linear forwards, fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 4s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
      to {
        fill: black;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="200">
    <text x="10" y="100" class="seriftext">
      Some text
    </text>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. Obviously, the OP has forgotten to set a stroke and a stroke width. These details should be included to help other users struggling with similar problems